# transform scale bug for fixed width elements

Tags: css, position, transform, scale

I have a problem with transform scale.

I have some elements with static width and i want to scale it on small
viewports ( < 768px). But if i use "transfrom: scale()" position of elemets is wrong, not in the center. "transform-origin" doesn't help. I can't use responsive width. only static 280px and 840px
[example on codepen](http://codepen.io/OxanaNana/pen/ozdwNZ)

codepen html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-list">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen css

```
.container {
  max-width: 840px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item-list {
  display: table;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.34);
  -moz-transform: scale(.34);
  transform: scale(.34);
}

.item {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 280px;
  height: 634px;
  background: #000;
}

.item:first-child {
  background: #234;
}

.item:last-child {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item-list {
     -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with `min-width:280px` on `.item` .

this style is set for under 768px. 3x280px is greater than 768 and so...the problem with the alignment.

i suggest you use `min-width:33.33%` width `max-width:280px` ( if you want to keep this, or you can discard it ) plus add `width:100%` to `.item-list`

see snippet below or [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vc6cfa4e/)

let me know if it helps

```css
.container {
  max-width: 840px;
  border: 1px solid #000;

  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.item-list {
  display: table;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.34);
  -moz-transform: scale(.34);
  transform: scale(.34);
  width:100%;
}

.item {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width:33.33%;
  height: 634px;
  background: #000;
}

.item:first-child {
  background: #234;
}

.item:last-child {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item-list {
     -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  .item {
       min-width:33.33%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-list">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**OR** you can set UNDER 768px `min-width:33.33%` ( together with `width:100%` on `item-list` ) and OVER 768px `min-width:280px;`

see snippet or [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vc6cfa4e/1/)

```css
.container {
  max-width: 840px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item-list {
  display: table;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.34);
  -moz-transform: scale(.34);
  transform: scale(.34);
  width:100%;
}

.item {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 33.33%;
  height: 634px;
  background: #000;
}

.item:first-child {
  background: #234;
}

.item:last-child {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item-list {
     -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  .item {
    min-width: 280px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-list">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** don't forget to add `box-sizing:border-box` on `.container` . because you have a style of `border:1px` so it becomes higher and wider by 2px ( 842px x 842px instead of 840px x 840px ) . and so, you need to set `box-sizing`

Comment: i know that my problem with static width. i have such structure and scripts that i cant' use percentage, only 280px and 840px. ( i add box-sizing in example)

Comment: well. you understand that 3x280 = 840 > 768 . and that's why it causes this error . try using `min-width:280px` only OVER ( in the media query ) and can you use `width:100%` on `.item-list` ?

Comment: 768 < 840, this is why i use transform scale. is it possible to scale block width 840px in screen with 320px. i used zoom property, but it doesn't work on firefox